# Store app version by default in Mixpanel

Tags: ios, swift, mixpanel

I need to make Mixpanel to store my app version.

It is storing all other things like Operating System, OS Version, Model and Manufacturer by default.

But it's not storing app version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mixpanel sends a number of parameters by default, such as the device model, operating system version and time zone. But sometimes you may want to have some properties that you want to include in each event you send. Mixpanel has Super Properties for this purpose. You can register the properties as Super Properties and then Mixpanel will include it in all events you send.

To register a property as super property, you just need to call `Mixpanel.mainInstance().registerSuperProperties()`

for e.g

```
Mixpanel.mainInstance().registerSuperProperties(["App Language" : "English","app_version_string" : Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString")])
```

you get the output as

[image]

Comment: It Works Perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To register the property which should be included in event body everytime event firing on mixpanel

```
val versionCode:String = App.appInstance.getString(R.string.version_name)
                val props = JSONObject()
                props.put("App Version", versionCode)
                mixpanelAPI.registerSuperProperties(props)
```

Even if we give same name of default property by mixpanel and it will replace the default property by mixpanel platform it will create new parameter with same

Reference - https://docs.mixpanel.com/docs/tracking/reference/android#super-properties